# Redirect Not Working?

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So My problem is that when visiting example.com/members I am redirected to www.example.commembers/ (notice that this is not a valid web address) instead of members.example.com (It only works correctly when there is the www). However, this redirection seems to happen with or without the following htaccess file. What to I need to add/change to stop this problem.

This is my htaccess file located in the members folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/members/(.*)$ http://members.example.com/$1
```

Then there is the wordpress htaccess file in the root directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your first rule. Change your code to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /members/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^members\. [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://members.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Okay, that almost works but example.com/members will redirect to example.com instead of members.example.com

Comment: I still have the same issue.

Comment: Rule is correct now. Try that in a different browser to avoid 301 caching issue.

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess in `/members/` directory? Also are there other rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: There are no other rules in the .htaccess and it is located in the /members/ directory

Comment: I'm getting somewhat conflicting results (works in firefox but not in chrome or IE) but I don't think this works either (example.com/members redirects to example.com).

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache. What about `http://example.com/members/` ? Is there any .htaccess in parent directory of members also?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44383/discussion-between-user1361852-and-anubhava)